# Add sort or search setting to a JQuery auto-complete?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have a JQuery auto-complete on a search text-box.
I have filled it with a list of names.
When a user types in one letter all the names containing that letter are displayed.

I would like to change it so if the letter A is typing in all the names starting with the letter A are show.

How can i add search settings to the JQuery auto-complete?

Below you will see how i setup the autocomplete, is there search conditions or something i can add?

```
$('#txtSearch').autocomplete({
source: Search,
select: function (event, ui) {
   //Do things with selected item.
}
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked :D

http://jsfiddle.net/Gm9Bz/14/

```
var json = ["JOAQUIN", "BERNARDINO", "MODOC","ALASKA","MADERA", "ANDERSON", "Kingston","Kala","Aka"];
json.sort();


$('input').autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    var matches = $.map( json, function(json) {
      if ( json.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) === 0 ) {
        return json;
      }
    });
    response(matches);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify what source returns to you.

```
var values = ['Andrew', 'Bacon', 'Charlie'];

$("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
   source: function(request, response) {
      var expression = new RegExp("^"+request.term, "i");
      response(
          values.filter(function(elem){              
              return expression.test(elem);
          })
      );
   }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N33zg/)

Looks absolutely beautiful in CoffeeScript:

```
values = ['Andrew', 'Bacon', 'Charlie']

$("#txtSearch").autocomplete
  source: (request, response) ->
    expression = new RegExp "^#{request.term}", "i"
    response values.filter (elem) -> expression.test elem
```